# Failure to verify dex file Out-of-order annotation_element name_idx

Tags: android, gradle, mobile, build.gradle, dex

i need your help. I got a Runtime error when updating my gradle from :

- implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
- implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.27.0'

to :

- implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
- implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.27.0'
- implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
- implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.27.0'

Error Log :
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: id.android.steven.dev, PID: 5539
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: **Unable to instantiate application id.android.steven.MyApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "id.android.steven.MyApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/id.android.steven.dev-2/base.apk"]**,nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/id.android.teven.dev-2/lib/arm, /data/app/id.android.steven.dev-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
                                                     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:846)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5944)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap3(ActivityThread.java)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1710)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
                                                  Caused by: **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "id.android.steven.MyApplication" on path: DexPathList**[[zip file "/data/app/id.android.steven.dev-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/id.android.steven.dev-2/lib/arm, /data/app/id.android.steven.dev-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
                                                     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1000)
                                                     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:835)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5944) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap3(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1710) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386) 
                                                    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: **Failed to open dex files from /data/app/id.android.steven.dev-2/base.apk because: Failure to verify dex file '/data/app/id.android.steven.dev-2/base.apk': Out-of-order annotation_element name_idx: 681e then 681e**
                                                     at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
                                                     at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:373)
                                                     at dalvik.system.DexFile.(DexFile.java:113)
                                                     at dalvik.system.DexFile.(DexFile.java:78)
                                                     at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:359)
                                                     at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeElements(DexPathList.java:323)
                                                     at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:263)
                                                     at dalvik.system.DexPathList.(DexPathList.java:126)
                                                     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.(BaseDexClassLoader.java:48)
                                                     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.(PathClassLoader.java:64)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.PathClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(PathClassLoaderFactory.java:43)
                                                     at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:58)
                                                     at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:535)
                                                     at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:568)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.getTopLevelResources(ActivityThread.java:2053)
                                                     at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:787)
                                                     at android.app.ContextImpl.(ContextImpl.java:2266)
                                                     at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2210)
                                                     at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2196)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5861)
                                                            ... 8 more

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if there is `-overloadaggressively` in your application gradle, this method force overloading all method. If you use `-overloadaggressively`, just disabled it and use another way.

Refer to [this](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/usage#overloadaggressively) link.

Comment: Solved. Thank you

Comment: how to use it  -overloadaggressively ?

Comment: @Sush check out the link that i attached.

Answer (score 0):

Mine broke after a Gradle update.  Fell back and everything is fine.  I assume it's related to the above.  The commented versions are the breaking changes.

gradle-wrapper-properties:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip
#distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-bin.zip
```

build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
    //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
```