# Execution failed for task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8' inJenkins

Tags: android, jenkins

> Task :app:minifyReleaseWithR8 FAILED
> ERROR:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/maroctel-android/app/build/intermediates/aapt_proguard_file/release/aapt_rules.txt:316:33: R8: Expected field or method name at /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/maroctel-android/app/build/intermediates/aapt_proguard_file/release/aapt_rules.txt:316:33
> -keepclassmembers class * { *** @{listner::onNextClickListner}(android.view.View); }

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'.

> com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, position: offset: 18684, line: 316, column: 33, origin: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/maroctel-android/app/build/intermediates/aapt_proguard_file/release/aapt_rules.txt

- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'.
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:187)
  at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:268)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:185)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:173)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:109)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)

I think it has some thing to do with minifyEnabled=true/false in build types
I am using Jenkins to make a build......
it throws error with setting
buildTypes {

```
    debug {
       proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'


        buildConfigField "boolean", "SSL_ENABLED", "true"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "LOG_ENABLED", "true"

        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
```

}

release {

```
        debuggable false
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        buildConfigField "boolean", "SSL_ENABLED", "false"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "LOG_ENABLED", "false"
```

}

With above setting locally build making is working fine but when I set minifyEnabled=true in Debug it throughs the same error In Android studio too.....

Gradle used 7.0.2
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 30

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65199308/10973828

```
<variable
    name="listener"
    type="com.example.ui.user.activity.ContactUsActivity" />
```

above code was missing in the layout where I was using listner::onNextClickListner