# Pro guard - Gradle issue - Configuration refers to unknown class

Tags: android, proguard

Hie, I haven't explicitly mentioned in pro-guard files but I am receiving this from my Gradle output

> Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult.ReleasableResultGuardian'
>   Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable'

but I haven't mentioned anything in `proguard-rules.pro` regarding those libraries.

[proguard file](https://pastebin.com/CBC1hpK9)

Comment: how is your gradle file look like?

Comment: @shizhen added the pro-guard file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57156980/7254873

Answer (score 0):

```
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

Put this line in your `proguard-rules.pro` and after putting this line the error will resolve in Android Studio if you want to enable proguard.