# Android Proguard - obfuscate method arguments and local variables

Tags: android, proguard, android-obfuscation

I'm using PROGUARD in my application. 
when I decompile the APK, I still see the original names of the method parameters and also the local variables that were declared inside the method body.

I was trying to use this rule:

```
-keepattributes !LocalVariableTable,!LocalVariableTypeTable
```

but still, when I decompile the code, I still see the parameters and the local variables.

Comment: Default values for Proguard should obfuscate this already. Have you tried without specifying any parameter, only keeping the default ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57156980/7254873

Comment: have you checked your `minifyenabled` attirbute?

Comment: @ArthurAttout yes, and it didn't obfuscate the parameters

Comment: @coroutineDispatcher yes, it set to true

Comment: @SumitShukla tnx , will try that

Comment: @SumitShukla didn't help, actually I'm using android studio 3.4.2 and gradle plugin version is 3.4.1 , from what I've read, with these things, R8 is enabled by default