# how to avoid method parameters from obfuscation?

Tags: java, android

How to avoid the following method name from obfuscation?

```
public static void testClassMethod(String testVaiable1,Stringtestvariable2) {
    System.out.println( testVaiable1);
}
```

but after obfuscating my method was

```
TestClass.testClassMethod(s:"abc", s1:"pqr");
```

my proguard file contains the following rules

```
-keep class com.example.mylibrary.TestClass**
-keepclassmembers class com.example.mylibrary.TestClass** 
 {*;}
-keep class com.example.mylibrary.TestClass{
    public void 
        testClassMethod(java.lang.String,java.lang.String);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57156980/7254873

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
-keepnames class com.yourPackage.TestClass
-keepclassmembernames class com.yourPackage.TestClass {
    public <methods>;
    public <fields>;
    #!private *; 
}
```

edit
Try this:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose

-keep, allowobfuscation class com.YOURPACKAGE.*
-keepclassmembers, allowobfuscation class * {
    *;
}

-keepnames class com.YOURPACKAGE.YOURCLASS
-keepclassmembernames class com.YOURPACKAGE.YOURCLASS {
    public <methods>;
    public <fields>;
    #!private *;
}
```

Comment: Did you replace "yourPackage"?

Comment: yes.                                                                                           -keepnames class com.example.mylibrary.TestClass
-keepclassmembernames class com.example.mylibrary.TestClass {
    public <methods>;
    public <fields>;
    #!private *;
}

Comment: Are you sure you did not miss anything? Because for my test class everything works. What is your gradle version?

Comment: -optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose

-keep, allowobfuscation class com.example.mylibrary.*
-keepclassmembers, allowobfuscation class * {
    *;
}

-keepnames class com.example.mylibrary.TestClass
-keepclassmembernames class com.example.mylibrary.TestClass {
    public <methods>;
    public <fields>;
    #!private *;
}

Comment: my Gradle version is 5.1.1

Answer (score 0):

update android studio and added the following two lines into proguard file

```
  -keep class com.example.mylibrary.TestClass{*;} - 
   keepparameternames
```

The above solution works for me.

Comment: fyi this will keep parameter names for **all** kept methods