# proguard Error in android app: -keep class com.gravityrd.* { ; }

Tags: java, android, proguard

I'm using this line of code in proguard.cfg:

```
-keep class com.gravityrd.* { ; }
```

related to the [gravityapi Document](https://gravityapi.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/RECO/pages/917522/Java)

and additional [java-doc](https://gravityrd.github.io/java-client/javadoc/)

Here is my **appguard.cfg** config file:

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# You can control the set of applied configuration files using the
# proguardFiles setting in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

# Uncomment this to preserve the line number information for
# debugging stack traces.
#-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# If you keep the line number information, uncomment this to
# hide the original source file name.
#-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
# Okio & Okhttp
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Annotation
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-keep public class ir.arvankala.util.SICookie2
-keep public class ir.arvankala.util.SiCookieStore2

# Gson
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes Annotation

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }


# Play services
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

# Play services
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**


# crashlytics
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-keep class com.crashlytics.android.**
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable


-keep public class com.adjust.sdk.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult {
    int SUCCESS;
}
-keep class com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient {
    com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient$Info getAdvertisingIdInfo(android.content.Context);
}
-keep class com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient$Info {
    java.lang.String getId();
    boolean isLimitAdTrackingEnabled();
}
-keep class dalvik.system.VMRuntime {
    java.lang.String getRuntime();
}
-keep class android.os.Build {
    java.lang.String[] SUPPORTED_ABIS;
    java.lang.String CPU_ABI;
}
-keep class android.content.res.Configuration {
    android.os.LocaledList getLocales();
    java.util.Locale locale;
}
-keep class android.os.LocaledList {
    java.util.Locale get(int);
}

-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer

-ignorewarnings

-keep class android.support.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.** { *; }
-keep class androidx.** { *; }
-keep interface androidx.** { *; }
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.ImageHeaderParser$** {
  **[] $VALUES;
  public *;
}
#-keep class com.gravityrd.* { *; }
-keep class com.gravityrd.** { *; }
```

but can't build app and i get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError
        at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.decodeValue(AnnotationAccess.java:688)
        at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.toAnnotationInstance(AnnotationAccess.java:663)
        at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.annotationSetToAnnotations(AnnotationAccess.java:633)
        at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.getDeclaredAnnotations(AnnotationAccess.java:161)
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.getDeclaredAnnotations(Field.java:234)
        at com.c.a.c.f.g.a(AnnotatedFieldCollector.java:79)
        at com.c.a.c.f.g.a(AnnotatedFieldCollector.java:41)
        at com.c.a.c.f.g.a(AnnotatedFieldCollector.java:36)
        at com.c.a.c.f.b.n(AnnotatedClass.java:349)
        at com.c.a.c.f.b.l(AnnotatedClass.java:321)
        at com.c.a.c.f.z.a(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:379)
        at com.c.a.c.f.z.m(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:308)
        at com.c.a.c.f.z.f(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:196)
        at com.c.a.c.f.p.n(BasicBeanDescription.java:251)
        at com.c.a.c.i.b.a(BasicSerializerFactory.java:346)
        at com.c.a.c.i.g.d(BeanSerializerFactory.java:216)
        at com.c.a.c.i.g.a(BeanSerializerFactory.java:165)
        at com.c.a.c.z.c(SerializerProvider.java:1385)
        at com.c.a.c.z.d(SerializerProvider.java:1336)
        at com.c.a.c.z.a(SerializerProvider.java:510)
        at com.c.a.c.z.a(SerializerProvider.java:713)
        at com.c.a.c.i.k.a(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:308)
        at com.c.a.c.s.b(ObjectMapper.java:3893)
        at com.c.a.c.s.a(ObjectMapper.java:3207)
        at com.gravityrd.recengclient.webshop.GravityClient.sendPostRequest(GravityClient.java:187)
        at com.gravityrd.recengclient.webshop.GravityClient.sendRequest(GravityClient.java:130)
        at com.gravityrd.recengclient.webshop.GravityClient.sendRequest(GravityClient.java:105)
        at com.gravityrd.recengclient.webshop.GravityClient.getItemRecommendation(GravityClient.java:415)
        at ir.arvankala.util.j$3.run(RecomUtil.java:125)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: NON_EMPTY
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:890)
        at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.decodeValue(AnnotationAccess.java:685)
        at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.toAnnotationInstance(AnnotationAccess.java:663) 
        at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.annotationSetToAnnotations(AnnotationAccess.java:633) 
        at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.getDeclaredAnnotations(AnnotationAccess.java:161) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.getDeclaredAnnotations(Field.java:234) 
        at com.c.a.c.f.g.a(AnnotatedFieldCollector.java:79) 
        at com.c.a.c.f.g.a(AnnotatedFieldCollector.java:41) 
        at com.c.a.c.f.g.a(AnnotatedFieldCollector.java:36) 
        at com.c.a.c.f.b.n(AnnotatedClass.java:349) 
        at com.c.a.c.f.b.l(AnnotatedClass.java:321) 
        at com.c.a.c.f.z.a(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:379) 
        at com.c.a.c.f.z.m(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:308) 
        at com.c.a.c.f.z.f(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:196) 
        at com.c.a.c.f.p.n(BasicBeanDescription.java:251) 
        at com.c.a.c.i.b.a(BasicSerializerFactory.java:346) 
        at com.c.a.c.i.g.d(BeanSerializerFactory.java:216) 
        at com.c.a.c.i.g.a(BeanSerializerFactory.java:165) 
        at com.c.a.c.z.c(SerializerProvider.java:1385) 
        at com.c.a.c.z.d(SerializerProvider.java:1336) 
        at com.c.a.c.z.a(SerializerProvider.java:510) 
        at com.c.a.c.z.a(SerializerProvider.java:713) 
        at com.c.a.c.i.k.a(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:308) 
        at com.c.a.c.s.b(ObjectMapper.java:3893) 
        at com.c.a.c.s.a(ObjectMapper.java:3207) 
        at com.gravityrd.recengclient.webshop.GravityClient.sendPostRequest(GravityClient.java:187) 
        at com.gravityrd.recengclient.webshop.GravityClient.sendRequest(GravityClient.java:130) 
        at com.gravityrd.recengclient.webshop.GravityClient.sendRequest(GravityClient.java:105) 
        at com.gravityrd.recengclient.webshop.GravityClient.getItemRecommendation(GravityClient.java:415) 
        at ir.arvankala.util.j$3.run(RecomUtil.java:125) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Any help please to solve the problem :)

Comment: Please post your proguard config file

Comment: i edit the question and add appguard.cfg config @Shailesh

Comment: Where do you declare `NON_EMPTY`? Is it an enum? A constant?

Comment: can you change -keepattributes Annotation  to . -keepattributes  *Annotation*

or you can use below line from my proguard config

-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,LocalVariable*Table,*Annotation*,Synthetic,EnclosingMethod

@Hamedmayahian

Comment: @Shailesh i just try your solutions but not work.

Comment: how about what @tynn said , where is NON_EMPTY declared ?

Comment: its related to gravityapi java library, I don't know much about that. @tynn

Comment: on the other thought , are you obfuscating third party jars too

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57156980/7254873

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're configuration regarding the *Gravity* API is correct:

```
-keep class com.gravityrd.* { ; }
```

The `NON_EMPTY` field is defined in the context of *Jackson* which is being used as the *JSON* serializer. As stated in the [jackson-docs wiki](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonOnAndroid):

> While there are no standardized settings for *ProGuard* usage, users have contributed sample settings that may be of use.

The most pessimistic suggesting should resolve your issue, but since *Jackson* isn't a small library, you might want to iterate and improve it.

```
# Jackson
-keep @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties class * { *; }
-keep @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator class * { *; }
-keep @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue class * { *; }
-keep class com.fasterxml.** { *; }
-keep class org.codehaus.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers public final enum com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect$Visibility { 
    public static final com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect$Visibility *;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`NON_EMPTY` is an `enum` field so try to safe all `enum`s in your package

```
-keep public enum YOUR_APPLICATION_PACKAGE.**{*;}
```

if it doesn't work try to use below code

```
-keepclassmembers class * extends java.lang.Enum {
    <fields>;
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
```

You can also add both of them to proguard to keep all `enum`s safe. hope it works

Comment: The error is disappear, but this solution Disabled service response, @tynn solution is work. thanks much